# Possible ways to make this `cartesian_product_with_filter` function variadic?

Tags: c++, c++20, variadic-templates, std-ranges, range-v3

I am trying to implement a function that calculates the Cartesian product of ranges. I know there's `views::zip` and `views::cartesian_product` available, and am just deepening my understanding of the use of the range library by writing this function with `for_each` and `yield_if`.

While it's quite simple to implement it on a fixed number of ranges like below code, I found no way to apply it to a function that has a arbitrary number of ranges.

I viewed [P2374R4 - Motivation](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2022/p2374r4.html#motivation) and found there's a `find_tuples_satisfying` which is similar to my code but returns a container.

The expected function signature is:

```cpp
template <typename Pred, std::ranges::viewable_range... Ranges>
  requires std::predicate<Pred&, std::ranges::range_reference_t<Ranges>...>
[[nodiscard]] constexpr auto cartesian_product_with_filter(Pred pred,
                                                           Ranges&&... ranges)
    -> std::ranges::view auto;
```

Can anyone figure this out?

[Current live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/zK1vcGhq5).

```cpp
#include <concepts>
#include <ranges>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

#include <fmt/core.h>
#include <fmt/ranges.h>
#include <range/v3/all.hpp>

inline constexpr auto for_each{[] [[nodiscard]] (auto&& function) {
  return std::views::transform(std::forward<decltype(function)>(function))
         | std::views::join;
}};

inline constexpr auto yield_if{
    [] [[nodiscard]] (bool should_yield, auto&& value) {
      // std::views::repeat(...);
      return ranges::views::repeat_n(std::forward<decltype(value)>(value),
                                     should_yield ? 1 : 0);
    }};

[[nodiscard]] constexpr auto cartesian_product_with_filter(auto pred,
                                                           auto&& range1,
                                                           auto&& range2,
                                                           auto&& range3)
    -> std::ranges::view auto{
  return range1 | for_each([&pred, &range2, &range3](auto&& value) {
           return range2 | for_each([&pred, &range3, value](auto&& value2) {
                    return range3
                           | for_each([&pred, value, value2](auto&& value3) {
                               return yield_if(
                                   pred(value, value2, value3),
                                   std::tuple{value, value2, value3});
                             });
                  });
         });
}

auto main() -> int {
  std::vector<int> const vec1{1, 2, 3};
  std::vector<std::string> const vec2{"hello", "world"};
  std::vector<double> const vec3{1.2, 3.4, 8.7};
  fmt::print(
      "{}\n",
      fmt::join(cartesian_product_with_filter(
                    [](int value, auto&&, auto&&) { return value % 2 == 1; },
                    vec1, vec2, vec3),
                "\n"));
}
```

Comment: The only reason `find_tuples_satisfying` returns a container is because the pipeline defining it ends with `std::ranges::to<std::vector>()`. If you omit that then you have a view being returned

Comment: E.g. https://godbolt.org/z/9fY1cr6vj

Comment: @Caleth I mean the *before* function instead the *after* function. I'm trying to implement  `cartesian_product_with_filter` without `views::cartesian_product`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The usual way of writing a variadic funciton like this is to split it up into cases:

- the base case (0 or 1 elements, depending on the context)
- the recursive case (some number of elements on top of that)

Now, writing `cartesian_product_with_filter` recursively is a little hard - because of how to propagate the filter part. So instead, I'm just going to walk through `cartesian_product` itself (since then adding the `filter` at the end is easy).

Note in advance: this is not a great implementation of cartesian product.

---

Our base case here is going to be 1 range, since the 0 element case isn't especially interesting (well, it's actually pretty interesting, but let's just skip it). So our structure is going to be something like:

```cpp
struct CartesianProduct {
    template <typename R>
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr auto operator()(R&& range) const;

    template <typename R, typename... Rs>
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr auto operator()(R&& first, Rs&&... rest) const;
};

inline constexpr auto cartesian_product = CartesianProduct{};
```

If we're doing a cartesian product of a single range, that's not just outputting the range - we need to wrap it in a tuple. Since cartesian product is always a range of tuples. So that overload is going to be a `transform`:

```cpp
template <typename R>
[[nodiscard]] constexpr auto operator()(R&& range) const {
    return FWD(range) | std::views::transform([](auto&& elem){
        return std::tuple<std::ranges::range_reference_t<R>>(FWD(elem));
    });
}
```

Two things to note here:

- we need to make sure we yield the correct tuple type
- we need to make sure that we *forward* the range into `transform` and that we forward the element into the tuple.

---

Our recursive case is as follows: if we have at least 2 ranges, then we can peel off the first one and perform what in every other language is called a `flat_map`: we map every element from the initial range onto every element from the recursive call, and then `tuple_cat` the result together.

That's:

```cpp
template <typename R, typename... Rs>
[[nodiscard]] constexpr auto operator()(R&& first, Rs&&... rest) const {
    return (*this)(FWD(first)) | flat_map([&](auto init){
        return (*this)(FWD(rest)...)
            | std::views::transform([=](auto fin){
                return std::tuple_cat(init, fin);
            });
    });
}
```

Lots to note here.

I'm passing `(*this)(FWD(first))` rather than just `FWD(first)` so that I don't have to repeat the wrap-single-element-in-tuple logic. It's not strictly necessary, but that tuple construction is a mouthful so it's fine.

Then, `(*this)(FWD(rest)...)` in the body of `flat_map` is going to turn the rest of our ranges of `T`, `U`, `V`, ... into a range of `tuple<T, U, V>`, based on recursion.

That gives me two `tuple`s: `init` (from `first`) and `fin` (from `rest...`), which we now have to `tuple_cat` together. In both cases, `auto` is fine because we know it's always a prvalue anyway - these are always ranges of rvalue tuples.

---

Once we have `cartesian_product` implemented, adding a filter on top of that is  just that: adding a filter on top:

```cpp
inline constexpr auto cartesian_product_with_filter =
    [] [[nodiscard]] (auto pred, auto&&... ranges){
        return cartesian_product(FWD(ranges)...)
            | std::views::filter([=](auto tuple){
                  return std::apply(pred, tuple);
              });
    };
```

Note that your original implementation was capturing the predicate by reference, so it dangles. This one copies it. Should ideally move, but the important thing is that the `filter` owns the predicate, rather than simply referring to it.

Also note that `auto tuple` is fine here because `cartesian_product` is a range of prvalue tuples, there's no extra copy in this particular case.

---

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/qETq83r65) of the complete implementation:

```cpp
#define FWD(x) static_cast<decltype(x)&&>(x)

inline constexpr auto flat_map = [] [[nodiscard]] (auto&& function) {
  return std::views::transform(FWD(function)) | std::views::join;
};

struct CartesianProduct {
    template <typename R>
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr auto operator()(R&& range) const {
        return FWD(range) | std::views::transform([](auto&& elem){
            return std::tuple<std::ranges::range_reference_t<R>>(FWD(elem));
        });
    }

    template <typename R, typename... Rs>
    [[nodiscard]] constexpr auto operator()(R&& first, Rs&&... rest) const {
        return (*this)(FWD(first)) | flat_map([&](auto init){
            return (*this)(FWD(rest)...)
                | std::views::transform([=](auto fin){
                    return std::tuple_cat(init, fin);
                });
        });
    }
};

inline constexpr auto cartesian_product = CartesianProduct{};

inline constexpr auto cartesian_product_with_filter =
    [] [[nodiscard]] (auto pred, auto&&... ranges){
        return cartesian_product(FWD(ranges)...)
            | std::views::filter([=](auto tuple){
                  return std::apply(pred, tuple);
              });
    };
```